# bash script a line of code i am trying to use

Tags: bash

I have a file that I store reservation into it and I am trying to remove the old reservation and put the new reservation if the same name appears before. 
does this line of code do it for me in bash?

```
sed -i .bak "/^$name|/d" reservation.txt
```

```
#!/bin/bash


#start by building a zenity command
ZCMD='/bin/zenity/bin/zenity --title=PA5'
name=`$ZCMD --entry --text="Enter your Name"`

cities=("Portland" "Vancouver" "Seattle" "Riyadh" "Jeddah" ""Las Vegas"" ""New York"")
departCity=`$ZCMD --entry --entry-text=${cities[@]} --text="Where are you departing from?"`

arrivalCity=`$ZCMD --entry --entry-text=${cities[@]} --text="Where are you going to?"`

departDate=`$ZCMD --calendar --text="Choose your departure dates"`
arrivalDate=`$ZCMD --calendar --text="Choose your arrival dates"`

bags=`$ZCMD --entry --entry-text=0 1 2 3 4 5 --text="How many bags are you taking?"`

#Summary of the trip info
echo "Travelers name: $name"
echo "Departure City: $departCity"
echo "Arrival City: $arrivalCity"
echo "Departing Date: $departDate"
echo "Arrival Date: $arrivalDate"
echo "Number of Bags: $bags"

echo "$name|$departCity|$arrivalCity|$departDate|$arrivalDate|$bags" >> reservation.txt
sed -i .bak "/^$name|/d" reservation.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You could try to execute that yourself and see if it's doing it for you. Then if the result is not as what you expected, include both current and expected results, and sample data in your question.

Comment: That will remove all lines that begin with the name. It doesn't add a new reservation, and doesn't check whether the same name appears before it.

Comment: Okay, how I can replace the old name reservation with a new reservation? if you want to see my code I can post it here?

Comment: `s/$name|/new reservation here/` but then you have the opposite problem; if an old reservation doesn't exist, it won't create the new one either.  Are you really married to `sed` for this task?

Comment: No, I can use different the "sed" but I do not know what to use?

Comment: I would probably go with Awk if you are only just learning. It is more readable than `sed` and allows you to do things in a *slightly* more atomic fashion (i.e. a ctrl-C at the wrong time *probably* won't ruin the integrity of the reservations file). A real-life application would probably use a database; SQLite is popular for simple tasks like this.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is that you add a reservation and then immediately remove it. You should reverse the order of the last two commands: First delete any existing reservation, then add the new one.

Maybe make sure that you use the `-i` option correctly -- on some platforms you cannot have a space between `-i` and `.bak` (while on others it is mandatory).

Comment: Okay, how can I do that?

Comment: In your editor, delete the `sed` line and paste it *above* the `echo` line so that it comes last.

Comment: Okay, I did it but it still keeping the same name reservation. is not replacing the old reservation with the newer reservation for the same name

Comment: I would like to overwrite the name if it appears in the text file already

Comment: That's the net effect of deleting if it it exists and then adding it unconditionally. Adding and then deleting obviously removes the thing you just added.

Comment: Demo: https://ideone.com/YO5uW1 (scroll down if you need to, I didn't see the final output line in my browser at first)

Comment: I am sorry, I am not getting that can you show me hoe, please.

Comment: Click the demo link. Read the output. See that it is correct. Observe in which order the code does the deletion and then the addition. I really don't know how to make this simpler or more obvious.

Comment: Thank you I had a very small mistake that I put a space between the" -i " and the ".bak". I just deleted and it works.

Comment: Updated answer to note this.